# initialization fail on struct

Tags: c, struct

I have been trying to run this before the main (no calls yet). It says initialization fail.
What could be the cause?

Compiler complains on the number of braces, but they seem ok.

```
struct contain {
   char* a;         
   int allowed;

   struct suit {
      struct t {
         char* option;
         int count;      
      };

      struct inner {
         char* option; 
         int count;      
      };        
   };
};

// initialize
struct contain _vector = { 
    .a = "John",
    .allowed = 1,
    .suit = {
                 .t = {
                    .option = "ON",
                    .count = 7
                 },
                 .inner = {
                    .option = "ON",
                    .count = 7
                 }          
              }
};
```

Comment: `.membername = ` is called member-initialization syntax, and to use it you need *members*, not just decls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually declare a member of the inner struct types.

```
struct contain {
char* a;         
int allowed;

struct suit {
       struct t {
              char* option;
              int count;      
       } t;

       struct inner {
              char* option; 
              int count;      
       } inner;
} suit;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare `struct suit` as a type inside the `struct contain`, but you never declare a variable of that type.  Neither `suit` nor `t` nor `inner` are variables.  You probably want something like

```
struct suit {
   struct t {
          char* option;
          int count;      
   } suit_t;

   struct inner {
          char* option; 
          int count;      
   } suit_inner;        
} suit_object;
};
```

Although since `t` and `inner` are basically the same time, then you probably wanted to declare that as a type separately and make `t` and `inner` variables of that type.